# How do I link to a CSS file that is in another folder, from within a subfolder?

Tags: html, css, directory

I am working on programming a very basic show streaming site for a project, and I have multiple folders. Folders include:

- HTML
- CSS
- Shows

Inside of the "Shows" folder, I have a subfolder called "Testshow".

How do I link a CSS file from the CSS folder into an html file in the Testshow folder?
I have tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

and some other things, but nothing has been working.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this from your html file `../css/style.css`

`../` it means one folder up 
`../../` it means two folder up

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Konstantin Savusia !

I used `../` before asking and it didn't work, but what you recommended did work!

I just added `../../` to the beggining.